# django 1.8 and 1.9 different way for the same operation

Tags: django

When I was on the webpage, the url shown as in picture A

There is a button on the page. When I click the button
in django 1.8. It turns to page shown as in picture B, this is the expected behaviour.

In django 1.9 it turns to the page shown as in picture C, this is not expected, there is more "change" in the url. In 1.9 the error info is:

> Request Method:    GET
>   Request URL:   http:XXX
>   Raised by: django.contrib.admin.options.change_view

I want to run the project in django 1.9.

The picture:

[image]

Comment: @Sam thank you very much.

Comment: Would you explain more about the page? where is it? is it for Django's admin default pages?

Comment: @kia  of course,this projecet is a ERP system. code is here:https://github.com/bruce201611/Django-ERP    And i have some screenshot, but i don't know how to addd those here.